# Display java console in a external jframe

Tags: java, console, jframe

I make a java application, but now I need to display all outputs of the console (like exceptions, println, ecc...) in a external jframe. 
I viewed some solutions but I don't know what I need to do.

Please don't mark this like a duplicate because I don't find nothing to solve my question.

I tried this :

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console console = new Console();
        console.init();
        Main launcher = new Main();
        launcher.setVisible(true);
        console.getFrame().setLocation(
                launcher.getX() + launcher.getWidth() + launcher.getInsets().right,
                launcher.getY());
    }

    private Main() {
        super();
        setSize(600, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class Console {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public Console() {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(24, 80);
        textArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        textArea.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                textArea.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
            }
        }));
        frame.add(textArea);
    }

    public void init() {
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't function.

What I should do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code and improve the solution :

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
    private Main() {
        super();
        setSize(600, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Console console = new Console();
        Main launcher = new Main();
        launcher.setVisible(true);
        console.getFrame().setLocation(
                launcher.getX() + launcher.getWidth() + launcher.getInsets().right,
                launcher.getY());

        System.out.println("1- log");
        System.out.println("2- log");
        System.out.println("3- log");
        System.err.println("1- error");
        System.err.println("2- error");
    }
}

class Console {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTextArea textArea;

    public Console() throws Exception {
        textArea = new JTextArea(24, 80);
        textArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        textArea.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
        frame.add(textArea);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        redirectOut();

        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        System.out.println("test");
//        throw new Exception("excccccc");
    }

    public PrintStream redirectOut() {
        OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                textArea.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
            }
        };
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(out);

        System.setOut(ps);
        System.setErr(ps);

        return ps;
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it function? If yes, what was the problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to display Strings on the console this will work. Maybe you need to convert more complex data to a String first.

```
package sof2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Main2 extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Console console = new Console();
    console.init();
    Main2 launcher = new Main2();
    launcher.setVisible(true);
    console.getFrame().setLocation(
        launcher.getX() + launcher.getWidth() + launcher.getInsets().right,
        launcher.getY());
    console.printOnConsole("BLABLABLA");


  }

  private Main2() {
    super();
    setSize(600, 600);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}

class Console {
  final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(24, 80);
  public Console() {

    textArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    textArea.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
      @Override
      public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        textArea.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
      }
    }));


    frame.add(textArea);
  }
  public void init() {
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  public JFrame getFrame() {
    return frame;
  }

  public void printOnConsole(String s){
     this.textArea.append(s);
  }
}
```

I added an function called `printOnConsole(String s)` that appends the submitted String to the console.
So in your application e.g you can just call this method with `console.printToConsole("I will be displayed in JFrame Console")`
This actually only works with Strings but feel free to add more complex data structures.

best regards

Comment: this code actually doesn't do right job with   printOnConsole().

Comment: the String that is used in console.printOnConsole() is displayed in the jframe. Wasn't that the question?

[Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/O8GGBpJ.png).

Comment: If you read question carefully you'll see the problem is redirecting system.out to a jframe, not only write a simple text on it.

Answer (score 1):

I based on the answer of @Razavi and i modified that to print the errors too :

```
OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
     @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            textArea.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
        }
     };
System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
System.setErr(new PrintStream(out));
```

Thanks!

Comment: I improved my answer and merged my answer with yours, to be better solution for other users.